# how can I set one pointer attribute so that it can call a function for an EXPECT_CALL?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, pointers, inheritance, googlemock

```
class Parent
{
public:
int* x;
};
//is I am trying to make an object of type parent, it results: waiting for specifier after new *
class Child:public Parent
{

void Func()
{
   <//DO SOMETHING>
}
};

//Unit test using mock
std::shared_pointer<Child> y =std::make_shared<Mock>();
//set_pointer(y);** //how this can be implemented
EXPECT_CALL(*(std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Mock>(y)).get(),Func()).Times(1);//this test is failed
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. What is wrong with creation of object of type `Parent`? What is `set_pointer` supposed to do? Why do you need the `dynamic_pointer_cast` instead of just making `y` be of type `std::shared_ptr<Mock>`?

Comment: I am trying to set x with the value of y, and I receive sgm fault at expect call

Answer (score 0):

If you are aiming at setting the `x` pointer as a result of call to `Func`, you can use `Invoke` with a custom lambda:

```
class Parent {
public:
    // most probably this needs a virt. dtor, but if shared_ptrs are to be used, it might be OK
    int* x;
};

class Child : public Parent {
public:
    virtual void Func() {
        //<//DO SOMETHING>
    }
};

class ChildMock : public Child {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(Func, void());
};

TEST(ChildMock, some_test_name) {
    // Unit test using mock
    std::shared_ptr<Child> y = std::make_shared<ChildMock>();
    // set_pointer(y);** //this lambda allows to set the vaule of x -----------------
    int some_x = 42;     //                                                         |
    EXPECT_CALL(*(std::dynamic_pointer_cast<ChildMock>(y)), Func()).WillOnce(Invoke([&y,&some_x](){
        y->x = &some_x;
    }));
    y->Func();
    ASSERT_EQ(42, *y->x);
}
```